# Hover.css border bottom effect is not working properly in Opera

Tags: css, sass, hover, border

I am using a hover effect from hover.css. It works well in every browser except in Opera.

It only seems to work in Opera when I remove the  properties:

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
```

But then, it doesn't work in Firefox.

I have also created this JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ta4sju8n/20/

But it seems to work fine there...

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Hover me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hover me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hover me</a></li>
</ul>
```

SCSS:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  li {
    padding: 10px;  
    a {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: white;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 8px;
      text-decoration: none;
      /* Border bottom animation */ 
      &:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        left: 0;
        right: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        background: white;
        height: 1px;
        -webkit-transition-property: right;
        transition-property: right;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
      }
      &:hover:after {
        right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Anybody can help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update:***

**Issue fixed**. I removed `perspective(1px)` and now the property `transform` looks like so:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
```

***Final Code:***
HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Hover me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hover me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hover me</a></li>
</ul>
```

SCSS:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  li {
    padding: 10px;  
    a {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      transform: translateZ(0);
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: white;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 8px;
      text-decoration: none;
      /* Border bottom animation */ 
      &:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        left: 0;
        right: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        background: white;
        height: 1px;
        -webkit-transition-property: right;
        transition-property: right;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
      }
      &:hover:after {
        right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```